# Selecting rows that contain subset characters in any order

Tags: postgresql

I have a table containing a list of English words from which I am trying to select all the words which can be made with a given string `"hand"` (as in the game scrabble)

```
+--------+
|  word  |
+--------+
| test   |
| father |
| woman  |
| zebra  |
+--------+
```

The query I have so far will only check that any of the characters in the hand are present in the word.

```
SELECT * FROM words WHERE word SIMILAR to '%e%|%z%|%h%';
/* returns test, father and zebra as they all contain either e,z or h */
```

However this does not take into account whether a word contains a character more times than the hand does, the code I am using in python to check whether a word is valid

```
def isValidWord(word, hand):
    """Return true or false can the word be made using the characters in the hand"""
    for i in word: # for each character in word
        if hand.count(i)<word.count(i): # is the character in the hand enough times
            return False
    return True # if every character in the word is present in the hand
```

My question is how can I build a query that checks each character in a word and making sure that the number of appearances of that character is not greater than the number of appearances in a string? 
Or is this not a job for a database?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's not the job of a (relational) database, to be completely frank.

Comment: Yup I thought that might be the case, I'm new to PostgreSQL I don't know if there is some inbuilt approach that would make easy work of it, alas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not the job of a (relational) database, to be completely frank.

Since the couple thousand words in English, even if you blow them up to all thinkable declinations, won't exceed a rough 100k words, I really don't see why you'd use a database for that, either. Just write it in python with an in-memory word list that you simply go through linearly.

There's several ways to make searching that amount of data faster, but a relational database can't apply any of them. Also, the speed gain should be negligible, considering letters are single bytes of data.

If you're worried about performance: yes, doing this in python does have a significant runtime overhead, because counting letters is very fast and can be highly optimized, but python itself is a complex language and executing it sets some limits.

Considering the amount of data to be handled to be rather small, my approach would be:

1. **Prepare a wordlist**: sort the letters of each word in your dictionary alphabetically, and use the sorted strings as keys for the actual words. You'll find that one sorted string can map to multiple words.
2. **Sort the letters of your hand**
3. **For every key in your word list, check whether it's a subset of your hand**. That should be really fast, because the previous sorting allows you to avoid redundant checks (i.e. if your at the beginning of your wordlist, the first word starts with an `a`, but your lowest hand letter is `e`, skip to the first word that starts with an `e`).

Tree structures of any kind could, algorithmically, be faster, but on most PC-style processors, nicely written C code will compile to very fast SIMD'ed string comparisons.